# Setup a PPTP VPN on DDWRT Router

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt

I have a internet connection with Static IP ,I want to setup a VPN for my Personal use
and my setup is given below.I followed the instructions for setting up a pptp Vpn from [here](https://www.dd-wrt.co.in/wiki/index.php/VPN)

**Intenet with static ip**-->**MODEM**-->**DDWRT Router**-->**System**

In this setup i am using the DLINK ADSL Modem and in modem DHCP is enabled and my DDWRT router is getting the DHCP address as WAN IP.

When i tried to connect the Vpn form another network ,VPN connection failed error message comming. also port no 1723 forwarded in router

Answer (score 1):

1. First, make sure that your router is flashed from your vendor’s website. You may get it flashed from DD-WRT Website using v24sp2 or higher version.
2. Next, go to the control panel of your DDWRT account, click the VPN tab under ‘Services’ and hit ‘Enable’ on the option for radio button. This will turn on the support for PPTP VPN server.
3. Now, you will find various options for PPTP VPN server configurations which you need to fill up in the manner below.
4. Server IP: Enter IP address of your router.
5. Client IP: Enter the Local IP addresses of the client computers or devices connected through the VPN.
6. CHAP-Secrets: Fill in the Username and password to authenticate the VPN connection in the format, (user[space]*[space]password[space]). Each line should contain the entry of only one user.
7. Once these entries are done, press the “Apply Settings” button to save the configuration on your DD-WRT router.
8. Now connect all client computers and devices to your VPN. The process for Windows is given here.
9. Go to control panel and navigate Network and Sharing Centre. Click the option “set up a new set up a new network connection or network”.
10. In the window that opens, click on Connect to a Workplace and then choose Create a New Connection from the next screen.
11. Next, hit “Use my internet connection” to choose the mode for your VPN. A screen will appear with the following fields: IP address/ domain name and connection name. Fill your IP address for DD-WRT router you configured just now and name the connection as per your choice.
12. Write the username and password with which you originally configured your DDWRT router and hit ‘Connect’.
13. Check the status of your VPN and internet connection by running the ‘ipconfig’ on your computer. If it shows your provider name along with DDWRT router information, you have successfully established PPTP VPN on your router.